# How can I populate a Library or List column name with the name of a file that has been uploaded?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, flow

Using SharePoint Online, how can I populate a column with the name of a file that has been uploaded?

Seems all the related Q&A I am finding have more complex twists, this I hope is straight forward.

1. File gets uploaded
2. File name is extracted and added to another column

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use file name in a calculated column formula. You can create a SharePoint designer workflow that runs on item creation and update the columns with data extracted from file name.

As you are using SharePoint online, I will recommend you to use **Microsoft flow** to do the same. You can use below action in sequence:

1. **When a file is created** - This will be your trigger after uploading a file.
2. **Update file properties** - In this action you can set your fields using filename you get from first action.

[image]

If you want a file name with extension then you can use **File name with extension** in Title property in **Update file properties** action.

Comment: @Dan Have you tried this? Is it working for you?